# In AppleScript, how can I generate the MD5 hash of a string in the clipboard?

Tags: applescript, md5

Is this possible in AppleScript? Do I just want to execute a shell command and then pull the MD5 from the output of that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `do shell script` command to run the md5 command:

```
do shell script "pbpaste | md5"
```